# How can I increase size of plotted area in wordcloud R (borders,as some of words are cut)

Tags: r, word-cloud

## I use Shiny dashboard and output of is in dashboardBody( box ( Output

```
    dashboardPage(skin = "blue",
      dashboardHeader(title = "Word Cloud",titleWidth = 320),
      dashboardSidebar(tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar{width: 320px;}")),
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem("Type",startExpanded = TRUE,
                   selectInput("selection", "Please, Choose Type:",
                               choices = books),
                   actionButton("update", "Change"),
                   hr()

          ),
          menuItem("Frequency",startExpanded = TRUE,
                   sliderInput("freq",
                               "Please, choose Frequency:",
                               min = 100,  max = 1000, value = 20,step=50)

          ),
          menuItem("Number of Words",startExpanded = TRUE,
                   sliderInput("max",
                               "Please choose Number of Words:",
                               min = 10,  max = 300,  value = 70,step=10)

          )
        )
      ),
###My outPut

dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          box(width=12,height = 12,background="yellow",collapsible = TRUE,res = 300,
              plotOutput("plot")
          )
        )
      )
    )[enter image description here][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IogCV.jpg
```

dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          box(width=12,height = 12,background="yellow",collapsible = TRUE,res = 300,
              plotOutput("plot")
          )

dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          box(width=12,height = 12,background="yellow",collapsible = TRUE,res = 300,
              plotOutput("plot")
          )

How can  I   increase size of plotted area  in wordcloud  R (borders,as some of words are cut)

Comment: Increasing the width and height should theoretically increase the size of your plot. 
Moreover, the link to the existing version of dashboard should make it more clear for people trying to answer your question.